# Program arguments (parameters)

Tags: parameters

I noticed that some programs can have parameters to run them specific way. I'm wondering how they work and where can I find documentation for them.
For example the Atom editor runs from `Update.exe` file but with parameters `--processStart "atom.exe"`. When running this file without additional parameters, nothing happens.

Comment: Start from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter_(computer_programming)) and if you would have more questions then came back and ask if you you miss something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Unix, most programs that take parameters show usage information when called with `-h` or `--help` parameter. This is also true for some of the programs running on Windows.
Have you tried that ?

Comment: I'm assuming by the presence of a file called update.exe the OP is on Windows. In which case, the norm is <filename> /?

Comment: Also, I don't know what atome.exe or update.exe are, but it looks to me in this case that update.exe is some kind of wrapper that calls atom.exe.

Comment: Yes, update.exe with parameters runs Atom editor. I don't know why there is no just atom.exe to do it.